# obiee count distinct by as part of total count distinct

Tags: oracle, count, distinct, obiee

I need create following "numeric distribution" report in OBIEE :

```
item name, 
count(distinct item_id by item_name), 
count(distinct item_id by item_name)/count(distinct item_id)
```

(third column should be percent of count distinct by item name / count distinct by total)
How to get total count distinct ? I'm stuck and i will be appreciate any help.

The result should be:

```
 Item 1 , 10,  50%
 Item 2 , 20, 100%
```

where total number of customers is 20, and 10 od them buy Item_1, and 20 of them buy Item_2

Answer (score 0):

Click on Measure in Pivot table then click on 'show Data as'>Percent of>Column.

Thats it